# Promise in nodejs with while loop not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
lib.connect().then(lib.wipedb).then(lib.init).then(lib.createDev).then(lib.creat‌​eDeviceModel).then(lib.createDeviceModal2).then(lib.createU).then(lib.createU2).t‌​hen(function() { return lib.createOrg("Park Hotels"); }).then(function() { return lib.createDeviceGroup("Okinawa"); }).then(function()
{
   var i=0;
   while(i!=100)
   {
     //Add Virtual Devices 100 Times
     // problem is i cannot add devices as the loop executes and does not
     // For Promises . How could i add 100 Users using the loop
     // Or If there are any another way to achieve this.
      // Loop is not working here but i need to add 100 

   }

}).then......
```

I have a test script written with a lot of promises. its on nodejs
earlier all value were hard coded but i now want to polulate data from JSON 
which contains arrays also.

the problem is the while loop gets executed and worst i am not getting any output.

please find the code below.

suppose i have  a

```
some.Db().then(some.wipeAll).then(some.getALL).then(some.createUser).
then(function()
{  
  some.addUser("abc");

}.then(function()
{

  some.addUser("def");  //Till 50 Times

}.then(function()
{

  some.showUser("sah");   //Till 50 Times

}.then(function()
{

  some.emulateuser("name");   //till 50 Times

}
```

Updated

i have a JS file which has all the functions and all these are based on promises.

```
lib.connect().then(lib.wipedb).then(lib.init).then(lib.createDev).then(lib.creat‌​eDeviceModel).then(lib.createDeviceModal2).then(lib.createU).then(lib.createU2).t‌​hen(function() { return lib.createOrg("Park Hotels"); }).then(function() { return lib.createDeviceGroup("Okinawa"); }).then.......
```

The above code works perfectly and the value are always hardcoded and the above process is repeated till 100 users. this is waste of programming modal.

So i wrote a JSON obj which contains all the user data in a array and rewrote athe code like this below.

```
some.Db().then(some.wipeAll).then(some.getALL).then(some.createUser).
    then(function()
    {  
      var i=0;
      var user =  // get all user details and loop thorogh
      while(i!=user.length)
     {
       some.addUser(user.name);
       i+=1;
     }

    }.then(function()
    {

      var i=0;
      var user =  // get all user details and loop thorogh
      while(i!=user.length)
     {
       some.addUser(user.name);
       i+=1;
     }

    }.then(function()
    {

     var i=0;
      var user =  // get all user details and loop thorogh
      while(i!=user.length)
     {
       some.addUser(user.name);
       i+=1;
     }

    }.then(function()
    {

     var i=0;
      var user =  // get all user details and loop thorogh
      while(i!=user.length)
     {
       some.addUser(user.name);
       i+=1;
     }

    }
```

The problem is that its not working at all and i cannot see any thing in the Db or html when opened.Due to use of promises for manual data entry its creating a lot of problem. I just cannot use a JSON with while loop
and geth thsi code to work. please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your `addUser`, `showUser` and `emulateuser` methods asynchronous and return promises?

Comment: Why are you *only* using `addUser` in your second example?

Comment: some.adduser() are async and have a Promises implemented. the problem is that it was written by some junior guy who just wrote it 50 - 100 times. now we have to add 1000+ users . we cant do this way. other files cannot be tampered i have only control over this.  I have to add data /user using a while loop but the loop executes without waiting for the promise to complete.

Comment: Yes of course, you're not waiting for those `addUser()` promises anywhere. But the original code that just repeated the statment did not either, so I doubt it worked before? Please post the exact original code (stripped from 50 to at least 5 lines)!

Comment: please ahre email. and i wouls mail that to you.

Comment: siddmegadeth  at  gmail dot com

Comment: No, no, just [edit] it into your question please

Comment: i have a JS file which has all the functions and all these are based on promises.     
  lib.connect().then(lib.wipedb).then(lib.init).then(lib.createDev).then(lib.createDeviceModel).then(lib.createDeviceModal2).then(lib.createU).then(lib.createU2).then(function() 
  {
    

    return lib.createOrg("Park Hotels");
  }).then(function() 
  {
    return lib.createDeviceGroup("Okinawa");
  }).then....... This works file but when i try to put it in a different way using a JSON it does not work . My purpose is to make it automated and can create n number to devices or users based on JSON